# Filebeat can't send logs after Elasticsearch cluster failure

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

We recently had a problem when ES cluster failed. The problem was resolved, but filebeat failed to send new data after the failure. 
Here's a portion of the logs - it seems to retry forever but can't send the data:

```
2019-04-08T11:52:04.182+0300    INFO    elasticsearch/client.go:690    Connected to Elasticsearch version 6.4.0
2019-04-08T11:52:04.185+0300    INFO    template/load.go:73    Template already exists and will not be overwritten.
2019-04-08T11:52:04.185+0300    INFO    [publish]    pipeline/retry.go:172    retryer: send unwait-signal to consumer
2019-04-08T11:52:04.185+0300    INFO    [publish]    pipeline/retry.go:174      done
2019-04-08T11:52:59.058+0300    INFO    [publish]    pipeline/retry.go:149    retryer: send wait signal to consumer
2019-04-08T11:52:59.058+0300    INFO    [publish]    pipeline/retry.go:151      done
2019-04-08T11:53:00.065+0300    ERROR    pipeline/output.go:92    Failed to publish events: temporary bulk send failure
2019-04-08T11:53:00.065+0300    INFO    [publish]    pipeline/retry.go:172    retryer: send unwait-signal to consumer
2019-04-08T11:53:00.065+0300    INFO    [publish]    pipeline/retry.go:174      done
2019-04-08T11:53:00.065+0300    INFO    [publish]    pipeline/retry.go:149    retryer: send wait signal to consumer
2019-04-08T11:53:00.065+0300    INFO    [publish]    pipeline/retry.go:151      done
```

I restarted Filebeat service and all data was sent to ES without any problem. 
Is this a known issue? Filebeat version is quite old, should I update? 
I'm running Filebeat 6.3.0 as a service on Windows. Elasticsearch version is 6.4.0.

Comment: It seems like Elasticsearch cannot handle the load. What do you see in logs of ES? Also having the same version of ELKB stack is always a good option.

Comment: @DebashishSen unfortunately I don't have access to ES logs. for now I tuned Filebeat to increase batch size and create indexes with bigger refresh_interval, we'll see how it goes

Answer (score 0):

Please show your profile
I have encountered this error before because I did not write the `procotol`
Below is a correct configuration file

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
  - /var/log/dmesg
  - /var/log/syslog

output.elasticsearch:
  # Array of hosts to connect to.
  hosts: ["http://192.168.13.173:30014"]
```

description : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/elasticsearch-output.html